# Sources of "morality of results" in mathematics

Tags: terminology, math-history, mathematicians

Long ago, I have heard [Itai Shafrir](http://www2.math.technion.ac.il/~shafrir/), one  of my differential equations mathematics teachers, claim several times that a result or a conjecture should hold "moralement" in French ("morally" in English). Since then, I have observed the same gimmick in several conferences (in French and English as well), by many people like [Haïm Brezis](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ha%C3%AFm_Brezis) or [Pierre-Louis Lions](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre-Louis_Lions).

So far, I have heard this statement mostly in the mouth of mathematicians involved in [partial differential equations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialDifferentialEquation.html) (PDE). Nevertheless, occurrences of "Morally we have" can be found in several other subfields of mathematics.

**Did someone else make the same observations? If so, where does "morality" come from, precisely, in mathematics?**

I do understand the meaning ("stuff that should be, knowing what we know"), and would like to trace the source of this expression, in a domain where truth is more important than morality. Especially, **is it more common in PDE or applied mathematics  as I have observed?** Are there occurrences in languages other that English or French?

Comment: From what I can tell, this generally applies to the idea that our mathematical model should agree with what we would expect about reality.   At least, that's how I've encountered it

Comment: Often a mathematician will use this phrase as a concise way of saying that  he/she has good reason to believe the statement to be true. In other words, true for some intuitive reason.

Comment: I believe I understand that "moral" here has nothing to do with "behavior". I am wondering whether this gimmick originates from a mathematician. I used to believe Haïm Brézis was a common denominator of the PDE mathematicians I have heard.

Comment: Just out of pure interes I googled Pierre-Louis Lions and read something about his Viscosity Method. Can someone give some reference where this method is explained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Moralement* literally means "In a manner consistent with the rules of morality".
It is commonly used by French mathematicians with the meaning 
"In a manner consistent with the rules of mathematics". 
Whether mathematics are moral or not is another story...

I do not know the origin of this expression, this is an interesting question.

**Edit**. Just found the following references from the [Dictionnaire de L'Académie française, 1st Edition (1694)](http://portail.atilf.fr/cgi-bin/dico1look.pl?strippedhw=moralement):

*On dit, Moralement parlant, pour dire, Vraysemblablement & selon toutes les apparences.*

Dictionnaire de L'Académie française, 4th Edition (1762):

On dit, Moralement parlant, pour dire, Vraisemblablement & selon toutes les apparences. *Cela est vrai moralement parlant.*

This is very close to the mathematical use of this word.

Comment: In English, "morally certain" is a common expression meaning "so sure one is morally justified in acting upon the conviction", with earliest cite from 1645 in the OED.