# Why does simplifying a function give it another limit

Tags: limits, paradoxes, indeterminate-forms

I'm asked:

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^3 - 1}{x^2 + 2x -3}$$

This does obviously not evaluate since the denominator equals $0$. The solution is to:

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}{(x-1)(x+3)}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^2 + x + 1}{x + 3}$$
$$\frac{1+1+1}{1+3} = \frac{3}{4}$$

**My question:** what is actually happening? How can simplifying a function give it another limit? Is it a complete other function and if so why would it be relevant to our original question?

Comment: Good elementary question +1.

Comment: The limits are not different. The first form is just a indeterminate limit of the kind $\frac00$, this mean that you need some manipulation to get the value for this limit.

Comment: This might surprise you, but 0/0 can be made to equal **any** number. In reality, you are not changing the limit. Instead, you are limiting the infinite range that 0/0 returns to the fnite range of a single real value. In essence, the first limit you obtained simply stated "this expression could be equal to literally anything". That is why it is called indeterminate; it has no apparent value.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: More accurate would be to say "any real number can be the limit of the form 0/0". Your phrasing makes it sound like $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x}$ can be set equal to anything you want.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Yes, Hurkyl is right, and your statement is at best misleading. Please don't do that...

Comment: @user21820 1. Please don't follow me around math stack exchange. 2. It is not misleading. I said the equation written purely as "0/0" can be changed algebraically so that it equals any real number. I mean this literally. 0/0 = 5. 0/0 = 7. And 0/0 = 1. I'm 90% certain I saw this fine at one time or another. It has little to do with limits and more about interpreting 0/0. I think it has something to do with multiplication by an integer resulting in 0/0 while simultaneously making it default to 1.Those two things in combination allows 0/0 to equal any number. But I may be wrong.It was a while ago

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: (1) You're paranoid. This was in the Hot Network Questions list. **I didn't follow you**... (2) That's false. As I said in earlier discussion with you already, "$0/0$" is a **meaningless** expression until you define it. The asker didn't, so it is meaningless. Seriously, I recommend you go and learn logic first. Then all these will become much clearer to you, as to what exactly is meaningful syntax and semantics.

Comment: 1. Well you've posted on a few of my posts lately. I thought maybe you were browsing my recent posts. There's nothing wrong with it. I just don't personally like it. 2. I wasn't saying it is defined. I'm saying that any attempt to give it a value results in it having *all* values. I did not make this up myself. I have seen it done multiple times without a limit. It's a very strange proof, and it shows why the limit can be indeterminate for all those values. It's like that because 0/0 actually could equal 3/4 (or any number for that matter) regardless of limit. Though, I admit it is peculiar.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: (1) I look through not only the Hot Questions but also Recent Questions and Linked Questions. That should explain it. (2) What you're now saying is not right, and I stand by my judgement that you need to learn logic. You said "0/0 can be made to equal any number" which means "$\forall x \in Number\ ( \text{We can make $0/0 = x$.} )$". That is false under reasonable interpretation of "Number" and "we can make", such as $\mathbb{R}$ and "it is consistent to add the axiom $0/0 = x$". This does **not** imply anything of the sort "the limit **can** be indeterminate ...".

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: What you **can** correctly say is the following: **IF** $0/0$ is a real number (and arithmetic on fractions are extended in the same manner to this 'fraction'), **THEN** pigs can fly and the moon is made of dark chocolate. Also, this issue has nothing to do with limits, seriously. Do read up on the rigorous ε-δ definition of limits and learn how to write purely formal proofs in some formal system using them, then you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @user21820 Euler [agrees with TheGreatDuck](https://imcs.dvfu.ru/lib.int/NEW/Math/MC_Calculus/MCet_Elementary%20calculus%20textbooks/Euler%20L.%20Foundations%20of%20Differential%20Calculus%20(Springer,2000)(ISBN%200387985344)(211s).pdf). "These things are very clear, even in ordinary arithmetic. Everyone knows that when zero is multiplied by any number, the product is zero and that $n \cdot 0 = 0$, so that $n : 1 = 0 : 0$."

Comment: @lastresort: Sorry, being Euler does not make one correct or even close to correct.

Comment: @user21820 that may be true but it is generally reasonable to presume such writings to be correct, especially when they become the basis for branches of mathematics. After all, Euler was right far more often than when he was wrong... At least, in the writing we use today of his. Also, nobody said it has to be a flawless perfect proof. It works as an *explanation* on *why* the limit is indeterminate. The author asked why the value changed. I'm merely stating it didn't. In that particular problem 0/0 did in fact equal 3/4.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Look I've had enough of this. I've helped you as much as I could, but now you're just pretending to know mathematics that you don't seem to. If you're willing to learn, I'm willing to teach (and learn), but if not I'm going to spend my time with other people. That very thing cited by *lastresort* is utter nonsense, and I don't care who wrote it.

Comment: @user21820 I never asked you to come here and chew me out because I made a simple explanation on *why* it is called an indeterminate form. The person asked why 0/0 changed to 3/4. He's asking about the fact that it had meaning and I merely explained something that is not a untrue or misleading statement. If you attempt to give the number 0/0 a value you find that by simple algebraic manipulation it can also be made to equal any other number at the time. I understand that the expression is nonsense. As I opened with in my post, this is the consequence of *attempting* to give it a value.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: You were the one who came here and made a misleading comment. Your claim in that comment was not at all what you're now claiming; it was "0/0 can be made to equal any number." If it had been "0/0 can be made to equal any number if you attempt to give it a value to begin with", then it would be perfectly fine, but still totally irrelevant, because limits **have nothing to do with** the value at that point even if it exists! In my opinion, I have the responsibility to correct your comment for the sake of other readers, not just you.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: You have ignored my recommendations in the past, but it is really you who need to listen to them if you want to learn mathematics. I'm going to say for the last time that you need to learn logic. After that, learn the rigorous definition of limits and you'll see that whatever you're saying here is not relevant. It is the equivalent of saying: "If the moon (0/0) is made of chocolate (number), then we can eat as much chocolate as we want (0/0 is any number we like). That is why a chocolate factory (limit of an expression of form 0/0) can provide as much chocolate as we want.".

Comment: Sir, I have learned logic. That's my point. You assume I have a lack of understanding of certain subjects that I already know! And yes, the value of 0/0 is relevent because the author specifically asked "why did 0/0 change to 3/4". *that* was the statement I referred to. I explained why the value appeared to change, because in reality 3/4 can equal 0/0. Yes, we don't expect it to, but it is not like 1/0 where is complete idiocy for 1/0 to equal 3/4. It makes sense, and as Euler wrote, it is the generally accepted explanation of what "indeterminate" means. It means undefinedness by ambiguity.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh - Hi, sorry had to write this although this here because there is no other way to connect. This is Nilotpal, 11 years ago, we were both the admins of the Orkut math community in the early days of internet mathematics. I have a math project in mind and wanted to connect with you to see if it interests you. Let me know how to connect. I am in Delhi 2,3,7, 59, 211, 13469 and neel@olpoints.com

Answer (score 70):

Perhaps you (and I think many beginners in calculus) have the notion that limit of a function is evaluated by plugging the value of the variable. Thus for the function $$f(x) = \frac{x^{3} - 1}{x^{2} + 2x - 3}\tag{1}$$ you say that its limit as $x \to 1$ can not be evaluated by plugging $x = 1$ because denominator vanishes.

It is very important to understand that *limit of a function at a point is something completely different from the value of the function at that point. A limit of a function at a point has nothing to do with the value of the function at that point, but it has everything to do with the values of the function near that point.*

However, there is a catch!! *There are many functions seen commonly in calculus for which the limit at a point turns out to be the same as their value at that point and hence for such functions it is possible to evaluate the limit just by plugging.* I think it is this behavior of some functions combined with the fact I described in last paragraph which creates utter confusion in the mind of a beginner. At one stage I mentioned that limit is not same as value of a function and next I mention that for some functions the limit is same as its value. Really confusing!

The only way to sort out this confusion is to learn to identify at least some basic types of functions which have this nice property that their limit at a point is same as their value at that point. Such functions are called *continuous functions*. Using a series of theorems on limits it can be proved in a step by step manner that *any function made up of algebraic (which includes polynomials and rational functions), trigonometric (direct and inverse), logarithmic and exponential functions using a finite number of arithmetic operations and compositions is continuous wherever it is defined.* The type of function described in last sentence is called an *elementary function*.

---

The function $f(x)$ given by equation $(1)$ is an elementary function and we need to calculate its limit as $x \to 1$. From what we have mentioned in last paragraph it is clear that we can evaluate its limit simply by plugging provided it is defined at the point under consideration. The trouble is that $f(x)$ is not defined at $x = 1$. Then *we use the fact mentioned in the beginning that $\lim_{x \to 1}f(x)$ has nothing to do with its value at $x = 1$*. The limit operation $\lim_{x \to 1}$ ensures that $x \neq 1$ and we can now use any sort of transformation on $f(x)$ under the assumption that $x \neq 1$ and *try to simplify it in the form of an elementary function which is perhaps defined at $x = 1$*.

Here we are lucky and by cancelling the factor $x - 1$ from numerator and denominator we reach another function $$g(x) = \frac{x^{2} + x + 1}{x + 3}\tag{2}$$ Note that both $f$ and $g$ are different functions ($f$ is not defined at $x = 1$ whereas $g$ is defined there), but $f(x) = g(x)$ as long as $x \neq 1$. Hence as far the limit operation $\lim_{x \to 1}$ is concerned both $f(x), g(x)$ have same behavior. And now we see that $g(x)$ is also an elementary function and it is defined at $x = 1$ and hence its limit as $x \to 1$ is same as its value $g(1) = 3/4$. Thus limit of $f(x)$ as $x \to 1$ is also $3/4$.

Comment: I think yours is the only answer that really tackles the confusion and its source.

Comment: @user21820: Thanks man! BTW when I was a beginner in calculus long back, then even instructors told that evaluating limits is easy: try plugging, if it does not work try to transform the expression somehow so that plugging works. Actually that is the practical method by which limits are evaluated in step by step manner. Unfortunately most teachers and books don't mention how this technique works and how it does not contradict the definition of limits. I have tried to sort this out and I am happy that you liked my answer.

Comment: When I was taking my first calculus course in university, I gave a trick question to my professor: Find $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{|x+1|+|x-1|-2}{|x+1|+|x-1|-2}$. His first (instinctive) reaction was to cancel them away and get $1$. =D

Comment: @user21820 limit is still $1$, right ?

Comment: @ritwiksinha: Its a trick question. Limit does not exist.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh if i understand correctly, then if a function is discontinuous at a point then we  try to convert that function to a different function that is equal to the first function everywhere and also defined at that discontinuous point, So that the plugging the value trick works.

Comment: @ritwiksinha: Nope. Both the numerator and denominator are $0$ not just when $x = 0$. For a (real) limit to be defined at a point the expression has to be defined for an open interval minus the point.

Comment: @ritwiksinha: Try plotting the numerator. I see that my trick still works even when advertized as a trick. *Grins* =P

Comment: @user21820: I have to admit that you are daring enough to trick your professor. I never tried to use such trick on my teachers.

Comment: @ritwiksinha: If you observe carefully, the function given by user21820 is equal to $1$ for all $x$ with $|x| > 1$ and the function is not defined for any $x$ with $|x| \leq 1$. Hence the function is not defined at all near point $0$ and hence we can't talk about its limit at $0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh i plotted the function,it is defined everywhere except $[-1 , 1]$.  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/p3scqefbpr,

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Then why can't we say the limit is $1$, Because if we evaluate the left handed and right handed limits for values larger than $1$ and smaller than $-1$, then those two limits will be equal.

Comment: @ritwiksinha: Thanks for the nice online graphing tool. I was not aware of it. We are asking about its limit as $x \to 0$. If the limit was about $x \to 1^{+}$ or $x \to -1^{-}$ then the answer is $1$. But when $x \to 0$ you don't have any limit as the function is not defined near $0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I was also not aware of that tool until i started learning calculus on my own. :(

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: It was a friendly conversation. He's a very nice person, and was quite amused when he realized the trick. =)

Comment: How are f(x) and g(x) now different functions? All we did was simplify no? LIke... 2x/x is just = to 2 right? but OHH... they seem different. 2x/x is not defined at x = 0 but 2 is just 2. This is... kind of crazy. I always thought simplification kept functions equal. Is this not correct?

Comment: @Jwan622: a function involves not only its formula but also its domain. Domains of $f, g$ are different.

Comment: So when we simplify 2x/x to 2... we're not winding up with two equal functions. What are we winding up with?

Comment: @Jwan622: the simplification does not work for all $x$. We need $x\neq 0$. If the simplification works for all values of $x$ then the function is unchanged. This is similar to the fact that equation $x^2=4$ is not the same as $x=2$.

Comment: @Jwan622 For most simplifications it's true, we get equal functions. However, when you see something like $\dfrac {x(x+1)}{x} = x+1$, there's always the unwritten assumption that $x \not = 0$.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh marvelous answer!

Comment: I bookmarked this post because of this answer. Fantastic work +1

Comment: @AlannRosas: I checked your comment as I woke up (this is morning time in India). What a great start for the day! Thanks for encouraging words.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh you’re very welcome :)

Answer (score 31):

By simplifying, you are removing the point discontinuity, also appropriately called the removable discontinuity, at $x = 1$.

[image]

Comment: It appears that the graph does not represent the problem correctly. The red point does not correspond to $(1, 3/4)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, fixed.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question of why or how.

Answer (score 12):

It's not that the simplified function has a different limit, it's that the limit of the original expression cannot be found by evaluation. In other words, write
$$
f(x) = \frac{x^{3} - 1}{x^{2} + 2x - 3},\qquad
g(x) = \frac{x^{2} + x + 1}{x + 3}
  = \begin{cases}
  f(x) & x \neq 1, \\
  \frac{3}{4} & x = 1.
\end{cases}
$$
Since $g$ is a quotient of polynomials with denominator non-zero at $x = 1$, its limit at $1$ can be found by evaluation. The limit of $f$ at $1$ has the same value, since $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \neq 1$.

Answer (score 12):

I think the important thing to understand is that the limit does not necessarily have anything to do with the actual value of the function at the point, or whether it even has a value at all. It's possible that the function *does* have a value when you plug the number into the expression, but that's still not the value of the limit (such a function would not be continuous). When you do the division you are actually changing the function from one that has no value at the point to one that does have a value, and the relationship between the functions is that the new one's value is equal to the limit of both of them.

Comment: +1 I always appreciate an answer which is eloquent, instructive, and doesn't sacrifice correctness to achieve it.

Answer (score 9):

Consider 
$$\lim_{x=2}{x^2-4\over x-2}.$$
We factor and simplify this to get
$${x^2-4\over x-2}=x+2.$$

In a elementary algebra class, we think of these two expressions as being equal. But they are not. Both sides will produce the same value for every $x$ except  $x=2$. The left-hand side is undefined for $x=2$ while the right-hand side produces $4$.

One good way of understanding the limit is to consider the graphs. Of course, the graph of $y=x+2$ is a line with slope $1$ and $y$-intercept $(0,2)$. On the other hand, the graph of $y=(x^2-4)/(x-2)$ is the same line with a hole at $(2,4)$.

Comment: so... is algebra all a lie? Are the two functions not equal?

Comment: @jwan They're equal as algebraic expressions but not as functions. In general everything involving polynomials is still valid when you substitute except when it gives you division by 0.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't get a new limit, it actually just didn't have a value before (because it was $0/0$), but it still had that same limit.  The original function and the new function are actually different functions that agree everywhere except $x=1$, for which the first has no value.  This is a consequence of the fact that when broken down, a function is just a rule for turning $x$'s into $y$'s.

Answer (score 5):

What's happening is the following: The given expression $\Phi(x)$ is **undefined** at $x=1$, but for all $x\ne1$ it is equal to some simpler expression $\Psi(x)$, which is defined and continuous at $x=1$. It follows that
$$\lim_{x\to1}\Phi(x)=\lim_{x\to1}\Psi(x)=\Psi(1)={3\over4}\ .$$

Answer (score 3):

The point is your limit is so-called [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form) $0/0$. If you have information that bouth funxtions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have limits $0$ in some point you actually have no information about limit of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ in this point.

Maybe more simple exmple will make this fact clearer. It is obvious that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3x}{4x} = \frac{3}{4}
$$
as $\frac{3x}{4x} = \frac{3}{4}$. But formally $\lim_{x\to 0}3x = \lim_{x\to 0}4x = 0$, so this is indeteminate form $0/0$.

Answer (score 0):

Such problems are dominated by what we call as indeterminacy, that is when you have at the same time zero at the numerator and the denominator, or infinity at both again when you are trying to compute such limits (if you had zero at the denominator but a non zero number at the numerator, the result would be infinity. But right now you can't know the answer). It is not that the function itself is changed, rather that you changed its' form in a way that you are "lifting the indeterminacy". L'Hôpital's rule is a really useful theorem that it enables you easily to lift such indeterminacies, thus calculating the limit.

Answer (score 0):

There is more to functions that mere formulae. Relations between $y$ and $x$ through $f(x)$ can be defined in many ways. For instance, for the identity function $f(x)=x$, you can write $y= f(x)$ (explicit form).

You can also find $(x,y)$ pairs such that $|y-x|=0$ (implicit form). You can use the [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) ($f(u+v) = f(v)+f(v)$) with additional constraints such as continuity and a fixed point like $f(1)=1$.

Implicit, explicit, functional definitions are more or less well defined and handy to use.

What you are trying to do is to  find a somewhat natural extension to a not-so-well defined function. Imagine I pose $y=f(x)= \frac{x}{x}$. It is not defined for $x=0$. But [morally](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434043/sources-of-morality-in-mathematics), since the function is constant for all other $x$, one might want to "extend" it at $0$, in a natural way, and the limit is one of the many possible natural ways, based on continuity. Then, you could draw the graph without lifting the pen at $0$.

A similar question is discussed in [Why is $y=\frac{x+y}{x}$ the same as $ y=\frac{x}{x−1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806179/why-is-y-fracxyx-the-same-as-y-fracxx-1/1806200#1806200), with explicit and implicit forms? They are not the same, but are closely related.

The simplification you use here is practice for more complicated cases. For instance, you can define or extend $\sin(x)/x$ at $0$. $\sin(x)$ is not a polynomial, but locally it is very to one ($x-x^3/6$), and then some simplifications may apply.