# Limit of a function at a point, undefined?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Limit of $\cos\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\right)$ when $x=1$. I believe this function might be undefined at this point due to the $\frac{1}{0}$ which appears, however I'm not sure if this is correct and if so how to show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we take the limit we are assuming that $x\neq 1$ then it doesn't matter if the function is not defined for $x=1$.

Take also a look here [Why are we allowed to cancel fractions in limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2628911/why-are-we-allowed-to-cancel-fractions-in-limits/2628914#2628914).

For the limit $\cos\left( \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \right)$the problem is that $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \to \infty$ and $\lim_{t\to \infty} \cos t$ doesn't exist.

To show that let consider

- $t_n=2\pi n\to \infty \implies \cos (t_n)\to 1$

but

- $t_n=(2n+1) \pi\to \infty \implies \cos (t_n)\to -1$

Comment: He's right, limit is undefined in the interval (-1,1)

Comment: @Karen The problem is not that $1/(1-x)^2$ is undefined at $x=1$ the problem is that $\cos t$ has not limit for $t\to \infty$.

Comment: Should the final line be $(2n + 1)\pi$?

Comment: @AdamJones opsss....thanks for pointing out that orrible typo!

Comment: I did not say that the problem is that $1/(1-x)^2$ is undefined, I said the WHOLE limit is undefined in the interval (-1,1), I gave you the reason.

Comment: @Karen the limit exist for any $x\to x_0$ with $x_0\neq 1$. What do you mean saying that the limit in udefined in $(-1,1)$? what is the limit as $x\to 0$? Isn't it $\cos 1$?

Comment: @gimusi, I don't know if Karen would use these words/had a formal definition in mind, but I expect they meant that as $x $ approaches 1, the [limit superior](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Real-valued_functions) of the function is 1 and the limit inferior is -1. It's just a bit of extra info beyond "the limit doesn't exist". (IIRC, Mathematica would output the interval $[-1,1]$ if asked for the limit.)

Comment: @MarkS. Ah ok of course liminf and limsup are $-1$ and $1$!