# Simplifying a limit with two variables

Tags: limits

let $f(x) = 4x-13$

How do I simplify the limit below to find if it exists?
$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

The limit involves two variables and I'm unable to remove $h$ from the denumerator.

I first tried replacing the function with its content
$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{4(x+h)-13-4x-13}{h}$$
I can do this small simplification
$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{4(x+h)-4x-26}{h}$$
However, I do not know where to go from here

Comment: Note $-(4x-13)= -4x + 13$.  This will cause cancellation.  Next, distribute the 4, and get a further cancellation.  Then get another cancellation.. :)

Comment: $f(x+h)-f(x)=4(x+h)-13-4x+13$ etc.

Comment: Proceed as $\frac{4(x+h)+13-4x-13}{h} = \frac{4h}{h} = 4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you made mistake here
$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{4(x+h)-13-4x-\color{red}{13}}{h}$$
it should be 
$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{4(x+h)-13-4x\color{red}{+13}}{h}$$

Given $f(x)=4x-13$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{4(x+h)-13-4x+13}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{4x+4h-4x}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{4h}{h}$$
$$=4$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't understand why $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{4h}{h}=4$$ If you replace $h$ by 0. You should get $$\dfrac{0}{0}$$ no?

Comment: $h$ in the numerator and in the denominator gets cancelled and you will be left with only $4$

Comment: @CedricMartens: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2628911/why-are-we-allowed-to-cancel-fractions-in-limits. (L'Hospital's rule is certainly not the “right” explanation here, in my opinion.)