# Verifying the limit of the expressions

Tags: calculus

I have calculated the limit of the following expressions as follows:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x \times \frac{2}{x}}{5x + 3 + e^{-2x}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2x}{5x^2 + 3x + xe^{-2x}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2}{10x + 3 + e^{-2x} -2xe^{-2x}} (\text{using Le Chatelier's principle}) = \frac{2}{3+1}$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x \times \frac{2}{x}}{4 + \frac{1-x}{1+x}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2x(1+x)}{4x(1+x) + x(1-x)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2x(1+x)}{5x-3x^2} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{4x+2}{5 - 6x } (\text{using Le Chatelier's principle}) = \frac{2}{5}$$

Are my calculations correct?

Comment: Yes, but why didn't you just simplify the numerators?

Comment: @Eval Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Bernard in the above comment, more simply we have

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\color{red}x \times \frac{2}{\color{red}x}}{5x + 3 + e^{-2x}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2}{5x + 3 + e^{-2x}} \stackrel{\text{by continuity}}= \frac2{3+1}=\frac12$$

and similarly for the second we have

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\color{red}x \times \frac{2}{\color{red}x}}{4 + \frac{1-x}{1+x}} =\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2}{4 + \frac{1-x}{1+x}} \stackrel{\text{by continuity}}= \frac2{4+1}=\frac25$$

Refer also to: [Why are we allowed to cancel fractions in limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2628911/505767)

Comment: We can cancel out x in the numerator and the denominator. Right?

Comment: Yes of course, I've highlighted that in red.

Comment: Will the solution still be correct if x is a complex number?

Comment: @Eval Yes in this case the solution should be the same, indeed we can simplify in teh same way and $5z\to 0$, $e^{-2z}=e^{-2x}e^{-2iy}\to1$, $\frac{1-z}{1+z}\to 1$.