# Question regarding limits of multivariable functions - is it really zero?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I am given the following problem in a textbook, and it's a solved problem.

> Find $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 y^2}{x^4 + 3y^4}$ or justify its nonexistence.

The author justifies the nonexistence of the limit in the following way: he uses the paths $x = 0$ then $y = 0$ and then, to justify its nonexistence, $y = x$. These are the author's notes:

Since

\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 y^2}{x^4 + 3y^4} = \lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 \cdot 0^2}{x^4 + 3 0^4} = \lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)} \frac{0}{x^4} = 0
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\lim_{(0,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 y^2}{x^4 + 3y^4} = \lim_{(0,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{0^2 \cdot y^2}{0^4 + 3 y^4} = \lim_{(0,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{0}{3y^4} = 0
\end{align}

but

\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,x) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 y^2}{x^4 + 3y^4} = \lim_{(x,x) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 \cdot x^2}{x^4 + 3 x^4} = \lim_{(x,x) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^4}{4x^4} = \frac{1}{4}
\end{align}

then the limit does not exist.

**So my question is:** are these limits

\begin{align}
\lim_{(0,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{0}{3y^4} \qquad \lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)} \frac{0}{x^4}
\end{align}

really equal to zero? Shouldn't they be indeterminate, given that the variable on the denominator approaches zero?

Comment: Well they *approach* to $0$, but *aren't* $0$, what you should have written in the next step is that e.g. $\lim 0/3y^4 = \lim 0 = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, both those limits are indeed defined and equal to zero.

The multivariable context is adding unnecessary "noise" here. Consider the simpler expression $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{0\over x},$$ which already captures what's going on.

Remember the *precise* definition of a limit. Colloquially, we often say something like "$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$ iff I can get $f$ to be as close as I want to $L$ just by requiring that $x$ be sufficiently close to $a$." However, this misses a very important point which is explicit in the precise formal definition: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L\iff \forall \epsilon>0\exists \delta>0\forall x((\color{red}{0<}\vert x-a\vert<\delta)\implies (\vert f(x)-L\vert<\epsilon)).$$ Note the "$0<$" clause in the left hand side: what this says is that we ignore the specific behavior of $f$ at exactly $a$.

This is why $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{0\over x}=0$, despite the bad behavior when $x$ is exactly $0$: for any $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta=17$ (say); then it's easy to check that for any $x$ within $17$ of $0$ *but not actually equal to  $0$*, we have $\vert{0\over x}-0\vert<\epsilon$.

---

A reasonable question at this point is *why* we define limits this way. Ultimately that's a question that deserves a serious answer, but very briefly the point is that we're interested in what $f$ *"ought to be"* at $a$, not what it literally *is*. Both the derivative and the integral give great examples of this: in each case, we really want to divide by zero but that gives nonsense, so instead we look at what happens when the change in $x$ or the width of our rectangles gets really close to zero without actually being zero. This also gives a nice spin on continuity: intuitively, a function is continuous if it always *is* what it *ought* to be.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, $\lim_\limits{(0,y)\to (0,0)} \frac {0}{3y^4} = 0$  since for all $y$ in the neighborhood of $0, f(0,y) < \epsilon$

However that is not sufficient for $\lim_\limits{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac {x^2y^2}{x^4+3y^4}$ .  Because 
$\lim_\limits{(y,y)\to (0,0)} = \frac {y^4}{4y^4} = \frac {1}{4}.$

If the limit exists, it must be have the same value (be within $\epsilon$ of it at least) for all $x,y$ in the neighborhood.

Answer (score -1):

Both limit

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{(0,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{0}{3y^4}=0 \qquad \lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)} \frac{0}{x^4}=0
\end{align}$$

are correct since the function $f(x,y)$ is identically zero along the trajectories with either $x=0$ or $y=0$.

In other words, what we cannot consider is $x=y=0$ at the same time but all the trajectories with either $x=0$ or $y=0$ are admissible and consistent with the definition of limit.

To clarify better that point see also the related [Why are we allowed to cancel fractions in limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2628911/505767)

Comment: This is not answering the actual question, introduced in bold at the end of the OP: 'So my question is: are these limits [...] really equal to zero? Shouldn't they be indeterminate, given that the variable on the denominator approaches zero?"

Comment: @ClementC. The answer was already contained in the point $$x=0 \implies \frac{x^2 y^2}{x^4 + 3y^4}=0$$ Moreover I've added a supplementary comment at the end to better aswer the main question.