# Behaviour of little-o in equivalence

Tags: limits, functions

The equivalent relations I know that little-o possesses are the below:

1) $f \sim g$ for $x \rightarrow a$

2) $f = g + o(g)$ for $x \rightarrow a$

3) $f = g + o(f)$ for $x \to a$

I also know about the following properties:

1) $f \cdot o(g) = o(fg)$

2) If f is bounded near $a$, then $o(fg)=o(g)$

3) $o(h) \pm o(g) = o(g)$

4) If $f \sim g$, then $o(f)=o(g)$.

And then the lecturer is making the following statement (for $x \rightarrow 0$):

$$-\frac{x^2}{2} + o\left( x^2 \right) \sim -\frac{x^2}{2}$$
From the properties that I have above I cannot make such a statement. I am trying to rigorously understand why we can write that. Perhaps using the definition of little-o should be used here? The definition that I have been introduced to, is the following:

> For $f,g : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $a$ is the interior point of
>   $E$. If there exists $\overset{\circ}{U}_a$ and a function $\phi:E
> > \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $f(x)=\phi(x)g(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to
> > a} \phi(x) = 0$, then $f=o(g)$ for $x \rightarrow a$.

I think the clearest definition for me would be using the limits. I would start with writing that statement as:

$$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\frac{x^2}{2}+o\left( x^2 \right)}{-\frac{x^2}{2}}} = 1$$

But this is weird. How would I proceed next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are mixing up different things.

Firstly we define the **little-o notation** as $x \to a$

$$f(x)=o(g(x)) \iff f(x)=\phi(x)\cdot g(x) \quad \phi(x) \to 0$$

which is the more general definition and it is equivalent to the following alternative definition

$$f(x)=o(g(x)) \iff \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$

which holds when $g(x)\neq 0$ for $x \neq a$.

Secondly we define the **asymptotic equivalence**

$$f(x)\sim o(g(x)) \iff f(x)=\phi(x)\cdot g(x) \quad \phi(x) \to 1$$

which is the more general definition and it is equivalent to the following alternative definition

$$f(x)\sim o(g(x)) \iff \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$$

which holds when $g(x)\neq 0$ for $x \neq a$.

In your example we have

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\frac{x^2}{2}+o\left( x^2 \right)}{-\frac{x^2}{2}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\frac{1}{2}+o\left( 1 \right)}{-\frac{1}{2}} =1$$

and according to the definition of asymptotic equivalent we say that as $x \to 0$

$$-\frac{x^2}{2} + o\left( x^2 \right) \sim -\frac{x^2}{2}$$

To evaluate the limit we have simply cancel out a factor $x^2$ using the properties for little-o notation. For that point, I also suggest to refer to the related

- [Why are we allowed to cancel fractions in limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2628911/505767)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84646/discussion-on-answer-by-gimusi-behaviour-of-little-o-in-equivalence).

Comment: can't see any maths now... Chats do not render MathJax

Comment: .... Those chats should support MathJax....

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal Yes there is the possibility to use MathJax also in chat mode, I'll give you the link to do that.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal Take a look [HERE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1088/505767)