# Sum of little o

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, asymptotics

Is it true the following?
$$o\left(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\right)+o\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=o\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right), \text{ for}\, n\to\infty$$
where $\alpha>1$.

I think yes since I know that $o(x^n)+o(x^m)=o(x^p)$, where $p=\min\{n,m\}$, for $x\to 0$.

So now I have to consider that my $x$ is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}$. Am I right?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for writing $o({1\over n+1})$ instead of $o({1\over n})$?

Comment: Do you mean I can write: $o\left(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\right)+o\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=o\left(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\right)+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$?

Comment: I don't see why not, unless $o({1\over n+1})=o({1\over n})$ is, in effect, what you're supposed to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your idea is right, indeed we have that by definition

$$o\left(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\right)=\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\cdot \omega_1(n)$$

$$o\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot \omega_2(n)$$

with $\omega_1(n)\to 0$ and $\omega_2(n)\to 0$, then

$$o\left(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\right)+o(n)=\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\cdot \omega_1(n)+\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot \omega_2(n)=$$

$$=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\frac{n+1}{n^\alpha}\cdot \omega_1(n)+\omega_2(n)\right)=\frac{1}{n+1}\omega_3(n)$$

with $\omega_3(n)\to 0$, then by definition

$$o\left(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\right)+o\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=o\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$

More in general:

- $o(x^n)=x^n \omega_1(x)$ with $\omega_1(x)\to 0$
- $o(x^m)=x^m \omega_2(x)$ with $\omega_2(x)\to 0$

then assuming wlog $n\le m$

$$o(x^n)+o(x^m)=x^n \omega_1(x)+x^m \omega_2(x)=x^n\left(\omega_1(x)+x^{m-n} \omega_2(x)\right)=x^n \omega_3(x)$$

with $\omega_3(x) \to 0$, then

$$o(x^n)+o(x^m)=o(x^p)$$

with $p=\min\{n,m\}$, which is the rule you are using.

Refer also to the related:

- [Behaviour of little-o in equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2960516/505767)

Comment: You may just write $\omega_i(n)$.

Comment: @user Sorry, what do you intend by $\omega_i$?

Comment: @Nik is a function which tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @Gary Yes thanks! I fix that

Comment: Ok very thanks! I will appropriately read your accurate answer! Anyway, even if what I have written in my question is not accurately explained, it is right what I have written?

Comment: @Nik Yes the result is correct. I've added all the details in order you can directly prove the property. You are welcome! Bye