# How to guess the output of $F(x)$ for $x$ that causes $0/0$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits, infinitesimals

As an example:
$$
F(x) = \frac{(1-x)^2-1}{(1+x)^2-1}
$$

When $x=0$ this involves $0/0$ and calculators output 'undefined'.

But when [looking at a graph of the function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wnnujkbamz) it is intuitively clear that the answer should be $F(0) = -1$.

Is there something that can be done with the function to get the expected output?

Comment: Yes, you can calculate the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to0} F(x)$ as well. Note that $F$ is not defined at $x=0$, so there is not "$F(0)$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One never "guesses" such an answer.  Never.

Instead, compute

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} {(1-x)^2 -1 \over (1+x)^2 -1}$$

which is undefined, so you use l'Hospital's rule, which gives the answer you expect.

Comment: [L'Hospital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) Thanks I'll check that out when I have some time.

Comment: Of course, this problem doesn't require l'Hopital's rule at all.  Just expand the expression.

Answer (score 2):

Using that

$$A^2-B^2=(A-B)(A+B)$$

We have

$$F(x) = \frac{(1-x)^2-1}{(1+x)^2-1} = \frac{(1-x)-1}{(1+x)-1}\cdot \frac{(1-x)+1}{(1+x)+1}=$$
$$ \frac{-x}{x}\cdot \frac{(1-x)+1}{(1+x)+1}=-1\cdot \frac{2-x}{2+x}\to -1$$

indeed then recall that we can cancel out the $x$ terms and take the limit.

Refer also to the related:

- [Why are we allowed to cancel fractions in limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2628911/505767)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0} F(x).
$$