# Can we obtain the following limit structure?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions

Let us consider we have the following equality in our hand as in the region $(a,b)$ in $ℝ$ 
$$\tag{1}f(x)=g(x).h(x)$$

1-) The functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous and their results finite (It means we can not see their results as infinity)

2-) And we know that we have the following features:

$$\tag{2}f(x_0)=0 ⇔ g(x_0)=0$$

3-) And the function  $h(x)$  is continuous in the region  $(a,b)$ . And its all results are finite and non-zero.

Thus, can we obtain the following one from the above-equation **(1)** with a limit approach with **any $x_c$** value in the region  $(a,b)$ ?

$$\tag{3}\lim_{x\to x_c}\frac {{f(x)}}{ { g(x)}}=h(x_c)$$

Notice $x_c$ include the zeros $x_0$ ; it means $x_0⊂x_c$.

EXAMPLE: Let me give an example in the region  $(-π/2,π/2)$ as :

$$\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cdot \cos x$$
Here

- $f(x)=\sin(2x)$
- $g(x)=\sin x$
- $h(x)=2\cos x$

Thus, we can write  without any problem:

$$\tag{4}\lim_{x\to x_c}\frac {{\sin(2x)}}{ { \sin x}}=2\cos(x_c)$$

And we know that for $x_0=0$  and $x_0⊂x_c$.

$\sin(2x_0)=0$   and    $\sin(x_0)=0$

Comment: If $f=g=0$ then we can choose $h$ however we want so I don't know how the last line would make sense in that case

Comment: If $f=g$ is the function that is $0$ in all rational numbers and $1$ in all irrational numbers; and $h=1$ then I also don't know how that makes sense

Comment: Please note $f(x)$  and $g(x)$  are continuous in $(a,b)$.  Please see my example $sin2x=2sinx.cosx$ in the question.

Comment: Ah, $f$ and $g$ are continuous; I see

Comment: In that case the section "Quotient rule for limits" [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Proofs_of_Some_Basic_Limit_Rules) should answer your question

Comment: Please see it again now. I f we repeat,   can we obtain the limit  (3) without any problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is true if we consider the punctured neighborhood of $x_c$ exists for which the ratio $f(x)/g(x)$ is defined.

We can consider pathological cases, as for example the trivial $f(x)=g(x)=0$.

Refer also to the related:

- [Why are we allowed to cancel fractions in limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2628911/505767)

Comment: Please see it again now. Soory, ı have not understood your comment. Can we obtain the limit $(3)$ without any problem?

Comment: @GUNES Yes of course in the case you give its ok!

Comment: Thank you. Can you give some more details why we can write equation $(3)$ ?  Is it possible for you ?

Comment: @GUNES When the ratio $f(x)/g(x)$ is well defined in the punctured neighborhood of $x_c$ we can take  $$\lim_{x\to x_c}\frac {{f(x)}}{ { g(x)}}=\lim_{x\to x_c}\frac {{g(x)h(x)}}{ { g(x)}}=\lim_{x\to x_c} h(x)=h(x_c)$$ since we can cancel out the $g(x)$ factor.

Comment: Thank you, it is good

Comment: You are welcome! Bye