# How to rewrite $\frac{\sqrt{x}-x^2}{1-\sqrt{x}}$ so as not to get $0$ in the denominator as $x\to 1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How may I simplify the following so I could calculate the limit without getting $0$ in the denominator when replacing $x$ with $1$?

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sqrt{x}-x^2}{1-\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: Have you tried multiplying top and bottom by the conjugate of $1 - \sqrt{x}$?

Comment: @CSchofx But the denominator will be 1-x which is 0 when x is 1

Comment: @TobyMak Same note above

Comment: You're right, the fraction doesn't cancel. Please add what you have tried and see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @TobyMak I tried what you mentioned exactly

Comment: @TobyMak I don't think this really requires a "what have you tried" approach, and I think the question is currently fine. They are asking about a specific step in the problem, not for the whole problem, and the specific step requires a rather standard trick.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{\sqrt{x}-x^2}{1-\sqrt{x}}= \frac{\sqrt{x}(1-(\sqrt{x})^3)}{1-\sqrt{x}}= \frac{\sqrt{x}(1-\sqrt{x})(1+\sqrt{x}+x)}{1-\sqrt{x}}\\=\sqrt{x}(1+\sqrt{x}+x) $

Answer (score 1):

Let consider

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}-x^2}{1-\sqrt{x}}=\frac{\sqrt{x}-1+1-x^2}{1-\sqrt{x}}=-1+\frac{1-x^2}{1-\sqrt{x}}=-1+\frac{(1+x)(1+\sqrt{x})\color{red}{(1-\sqrt{x})}}{\color{red}{1-\sqrt{x}}}$$

and refer to

- [Why are we allowed to cancel fractions in limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2628911/why-are-we-allowed-to-cancel-fractions-in-limits/2628914#2628914)

Comment: still the denominator is 0

Comment: You can cancel out the term now!

Comment: Is it right to distribute a fraction when it is indeterminate?

Comment: How you thought about adding 1... may you show the method if multiplying by 1+sqrt(x)

Comment: @DatBoi Yes of course, all allowed algebric manipulations before to take the limit are fine.

Comment: @john By this other way we obtain $$\frac{\sqrt{x}-x^2}{1-\sqrt{x}}=\frac{\sqrt{x}-x^2}{1-\sqrt{x}}\frac{1+\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{(\sqrt{x}-x^2)(1+\sqrt x)}{1-x}$$ which in inconclusive again. Precisely for this reason I've proposed a different way.

Comment: @john Another way let $x=y^2$ $$\frac{\sqrt{x}-x^2}{1-\sqrt{x}}=\frac{y-y^4}{1-y}=\frac{y(1-y^3)}{1-y}=\frac{y(1-y)(1+y+y^2)}{1-y}$$ which reveals more clearly the standard trick used in almost all others answers.

Comment: @john Don't forget the old good one l'Hopital $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{x}-x^2}{1-\sqrt{x}} = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}-2x}{-\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}} $$

Answer (score -1):

Let $r=\sqrt{x}$. Then $\sqrt{x}-x^2=r(1-r^3)=r(1-r)(1+r+r^2)$.

Comment: Why a downvote ? The trick is good !

Comment: I give you a +1 to cancel out the incomprehensible downvote :)