# Evaluate limit of this trig function

Tags: limits

I'm going through the first openstax calculus book and i'm struggling to understand something.
Let me process this limit as I think it goes and then ask the question about it.

Evalulate $$\require{cancel}\lim_{\Theta \to 0}\frac{1-\cos \Theta}{\sin \Theta}$$

> 

\begin{align}
\lim_{\Theta \to 0}\frac{1-\cos \Theta}{\sin \Theta} & = \lim_{\Theta \to 0}\frac{1 -\cos \Theta}{\sin \Theta}\cdot\frac{1 + \cos \Theta}{1 + \cos \Theta} \\
& = \lim_{\Theta \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos^2 \Theta}{\sin \Theta(1+ \cos \Theta)} \\
& = \lim_{\Theta \to 0} \frac{\sin^2 \Theta}{\sin \Theta(1 + \cos \Theta)} \\
& = \lim_{\Theta \to 0}\frac{\sin \Theta}{\sin \Theta}\cdot\frac{\sin \Theta}{1 + \cos \Theta} \\
& = \frac{0}{0}\cdot \frac{0}{2} \\
& = undef
\end{align}

I thought this would have been right, however the book says the answer should be $0$. All I can think of is if it goes like this, picking up on third-last line.

\begin{align}
\lim_{\Theta \to 0} \frac{\sin^2 \Theta}{\sin \Theta(1 + \cos \Theta)} 
& = \lim_{\Theta \to 0}\frac{\cancel{\sin \Theta}}{\cancel{\sin \Theta}}\cdot\frac{\sin \Theta}{1 + \cos \Theta} \\
& = \frac{0}{2} \\
& = 0
\end{align}

But I thought that's not right because for example,
$$f(x) = \frac{\cancel{(x+3)}}{\cancel{(x+3)}(x-1)}$$

Still has a discontinuity at $x = -3$

So the cancelling out doesn't remove the discontinuity and I thougt this would be so with the limit above also. Or is there some other way they came to $0$ that I'm not seeing?

Thanks.

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2628911

Comment: That's really helpful @user . Thankyou.

Comment: This is indeed the key point we have $\theta \neq 0$ and so the ratio is equal to $1$.

Comment: You are not plugging in $\theta = 0$, you are taking the limit as $\theta$ approaches zero. For any non-zero value of theta, no matter how small, $\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\sin{\theta}}=1$. The same applies to $\frac{x+3}{x+3}$. We are not plugging in $x=-3$ nor are we removing the discontinuity. We are taking the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the numerator, I suggest to write $1-\cos(\theta)$ as $2\sin^{2}(\theta/2)$, while the denominator is $2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)$. Then the limit becomes that of $\tan(\theta/2)$ as $\theta$ tends to $0$ which indeed is $0$.