# Is there a difference between $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = x^4/x^3$ in terms of continuity at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

It would seem at first glance that for any $x \neq 0$ we can cancel out the $x^3$ factors in numerator and denominator and have $f(x) = x$.

[MITOCW problem set 1](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/problem-set-1/MIT18_01SC_pset1prb.pdf) says there is a removable discontinuity at $x=0$ (problem 1D-3c, and the [official solutions](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/problem-set-1/MIT18_01SC_pset1sol.pdf))

What is in fact the difference between $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = x^4/x^3$ in terms of continuity?

For example, if I start with $f(x) = x$ and then multiply by $x^3/x^3$ is this different from starting from $f(x) = x^4/x^3$, with regards to what happens at $x=0$?

Comment: $x^4/x^3$ is not defined at the origin. Away from the origin, the functions are identical. The limit for both at the origin is $0$ and does not depend on the value at $0$. The function $x^4/x^3$ is not continuous at the origin, because its value there is undefined. See here for a great explanation: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1822706/754927

Comment: The difference is that $f(x) = x$ is the function that maps to $x$ no matter what $x$ is.  While $g(x) = \frac {x^4}{x^3}$ is a function that maps to $x$ if $x\ne 0$ but is completely undefined and does not exist if $x = 0$.  $f$ is continuous everywhere.  $g$ is continuous everywhere *except* at $x =0$ where it is not defined at all.

Comment: "if I start with f(x)=x and then multiply by x3/x3 is this different from starting from f(x)=x4/x3, with regards to what happens at x=0?"  You can't multiply by $\frac 00$ if $x = 0$ because $\frac 00$ doesn't exist and is not anything at all.